# How to retrieve second value from search object?

Tags: python, regex

I am unable to obtain the second match from a match object.

**EDIT: found a fix**

```py
ptrn_buy_in = re.compile("(?<=[$€£])([0-9]+[.,][0-9]+)")
buy_in = re.findall(ptrn_buy_in, lines[0])
if buy_in[1] and buy_in[2]:
    parsed_hand["metadata"]["buy_in"] = float(buy_in[1])
    parsed_hand["metadata"]["rake"] = float(buy_in[2])
```

My string is: $14.69+$0.31

I have tried to see if the match object actually holds more values within the same group i.e. .group(0)[0] and [1]. This actually gave me the second digit of the number so not at all what I was expecting.

```py
ptrn_buy_in = re.compile("(?<=[$€£])([0-9]+.[0-9]+)")
buy_in = re.search(ptrn_buy_in, lines[0])
if buy_in.group(0) and buy_in.group(1):
    parsed_hand["metadata"]["buy_in"] = float(buy_in.group(0))
    parsed_hand["metadata"]["rake"] = float(buy_in.group(1))
```

I am expecting to get 14.69 in .group(0) and 0.31 from .group(1) however I am getting 14.69 twice. Does anyone have any ideas?

Kind regards

Comment: `group(0)` gives you the whole match, use `group(1)` and `group(2)` to get your capturing groups.

Comment: You have only 1 capturing group not 2

Comment: group(2) does not exist, however found a way with findall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only 1 capturing group `([0-9]+.[0-9]+)` which will match 1+ digits, 1 times any character and again 1+ digits.

[re.search](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) returns a [MatchObject](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject) which where .`group(0)` returns the entire match and `.group(1)` the first capturing group. That is why you get 14.69 twice.

You have to escape the dot to match it literally. But as you use a positive lookbehind, you could omit the group and get the match only:

```
(?<=[$€£])[0-9]+\.[0-9]+

ptrn_buy_in = re.compile("(?<=[$€£])[0-9]+\.[0-9]+")
print(re.findall(ptrn_buy_in, r"$14.69+$0.31"))
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dmmefY/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/U8jP9v)

Result

```
['14.69', '0.31']
```

Or use a match with the capturing group:

```
[$€£]([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dmmefY/2) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/rImVX0)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, clarifies things a lot!